# Redirect first page of pagination to main page

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have page url with pagination. Parameter category my be different

For exemple: `http://domain.com/category?p=1`

How can I redirect this url to: `http://domain.com/category` using .htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With that:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^p=1$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1 [R=302,QSD,L]
```

`[QSD]` work only since Apache 2.4.0. If it's not your case, use:

```
 RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1? [R=302,L]
```

Change R=302 for R=301 when test work well.

Comment: +1 for mentioning about `QSD` and version compatibility.

Comment: @anubhava Thanks, I learned everything from you, 
except English... ;-)